# Macro to loop through Sheets with muliple IFs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that is supposed to look though all worksheets in the current workbook (excluding a few named ones) and, if certain cells meet certain conditions, then do things to the sheet, and loop though all sheets indefinately until the sub is terminated manually.

However I'm getting errors. I'm not sure if its the way I'm identifying the cells or the structure of my Ifs. Any thoughts much appreciated.

```
Sub Update()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.name <> "B" Or ws.name <> "BO" Or ws.name <> "MS" Then

    ws.Range("B9").value = ws.Range("B9").value + 1

    End If

    If ws.Range("D1").value = 5 Then
    ws.Range("D1").value = ws.Range("D1").value + 1

    Next ws

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "Update"

End Sub
```

Comment: Your logic is incorrect in your first IF statement. You should be using AND instead of OR. EG: If its NOT B and NOT BO and NOT MS, then [exectue conditional code]. A worksheet named "B" for instance fails on the first statement, but succeeds on the 2nd and 3rd statements when compraed to BO and MS, so it still executes the statement. False OR True OR True = True.

Comment: What errors do you get? Which row of code produces these errors?

Comment: You're missing an `End If` statement - probably just before `Next ws`

Comment: Thanks Kris it doesn't seem to be affecting the excluded sheets but I'll check.

Comment: Vacip it won't get past the first ws.range at the moment.. 'type mismatch' error.

Comment: Kris you're a genius - that wasn't what the errors were saying but fixing it made it work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Kris detailed in his comment your Boolean logic is not accurate - you need to swap the `OR`s for `AND`s.
Your second `IF` would be tidier with and `End If`

What is the purpose of the last line in the routine?

```
Sub Update()

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
For Each ws In Excel.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

  If (ws.name <> "B") AND 
       (ws.name <> "BO") AND 
         (ws.name <> "MS") Then
      ws.Range("B9").value = ws.Range("B9").value + 1
  End If

  If (ws.Range("D1").value = 5) Then
    ws.Range("D1").value = ws.Range("D1").value + 1
  End If
Next ws

Excel.Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "Update"
End Sub
```